# Should I use the past simple "I learned", or the present perfect "I've learned"?

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect, past-simple

Please explain which is correct:

- I've learned to ride a bicycle when I was five
- I learned to ride a bicycle when I was five

For me both of them are correct.

Comment: *I learned to ride a bicycle when I was five*. This learning activity is in the past and finished. Use "I've..."  when you are reporting on a past experience. e.g. ***I've heard** this song (before)* or ***I've met** him (before)*. Notice you can also say *I met him* which suggests something slightly different than *I've met him*. E.g. *When did you talk to Smith? **I met** him yesterday afternoon for lunch*. E.g.2 *Have you met Smith? - Yes, **I've met** him.*

Comment: If you can't say the first sentence in your mother language then you can't probably say it in English, it's related to logic and semantics of languages not grammar or English.

Comment: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/62581/i-have-never-felt-vs-i-never-felt/62641#62641

Answer (score 4):

The **present perfect** is not used when a past event is finished and has no connection with the present.

> I learned to ride a bicycle when I was five. ✓

Age of five is finished (once) and there's no connection with the present.

---

**Present perfect** tense has a lot of uses. The most used ones are:

> 1. for an action or event that started in the past and is permanent.
> 2. for a past event which has a result now.

**Past simple** tense is used for completed events on a definited point in the past. The events have no connection with the present.

> *When I was at school, my favourite subject was geography.* ✓
>   <s>*When I was at school, my favourite subject **has been** geography.*</s> ✗ (My school days are finished and no connection is made with the present.)

Comment: Good example.  You can't unhear a song, that's a permanent condition.

Answer (score 2):

I have learned to ride a bicycle when I was five.

"When I was five"is a subordinate/time clause.  According to grammar, when this clause refers to the past, we use either the past simple or the past perfect depending on the context of a sentence.  When it's so, the main clause is also in the past tense.

So the use of the present perfect in the main clause is grammatically incorrect; the tenses of both the clauses should be past.  So the correct sentence is:

I learned to ride a bicycle when I was five.

Answer (score 1):

To refer to the act of learning to ride a bicycle when the speaker was five years old, the ***Simple Past Tense*** should be used : ***"I learned to ride a bicycle when I was five"***

***Present Perfect Tense*** is used to refer to an action that has been completed , finished, or done just now or a little time back (in the '*immediate past*').

As the act of learning to ride a bicycle did not happen in the '*immediate past*', so we cannot use Present Perfect Tense. It can used in the following way : ***"I've learned to ride a bicycle"***; in this case it would mean that the speaker has learned to ride a bicycle in the '*immediate past*'.

Comment: To continue that thought, the only way you'd include the age in the present perfect tense is if you're still at that age (and are perhaps boasting about the achievement a little bit), as in: _I've learned to ride a bicycle and I'm still just five!_

Comment: Note that the present perfect is **not** confined to recent events. It mentions past events, which may be indefinitely remote, as the cause or source of a *present* state. I can say that I've learned three languages (to some extent), although I have not studied any of them since I was a teenager in the 1960s.

Comment: Are there ESL classes that teaches that present perfect can only be used for the *immediate past*? Because a lot of people here seem to believe that, and it's not really true.

Comment: @PeterShor Perhaps B Guarev meant *I've just learned to ride a bicycle*.