# I have never felt VS I never felt

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple

The use of the Present Perfect and Simple Past in these sentences has always confused me. Which use is correct? And is there a difference?

Here is what I know. I use the Present Perfect to talk about something that might have happened at any point in my life. **For example,

> In my whole life, I **have felt** appreciated twice.

I use the Past Simple to talk about something that happened in the past and is finished. For example,

> I **felt** appreciated yesterday.

Shouldn't the following sentence use the Present Perfect tense?

> I **have never felt** appreciated in my whole life.

or

> I **never felt** appreciated in my whole life.**

In making sure that the sentence should be in the Present Perfect tense,  isn't the correct question to these sentence is the Present Prefect one?
Have you ever felt appreciated?

Answer (score 3):

1. We use the **present perfect** to talk about an experience at any time in the past. The exact time of the experience isn't important.

   > *I've seen the latest Megan Fox Film.* *Have you ever been to Spain?*
2. We use the **past simple** to talk about a specific occassion in the past.

   > *I saw the latest Jim Carrey film last night.* *Did you go to Spain last summer?*

---

So, in your example, the tense is,

> *I have never felt appreciated in my whole life.*

Comment: But a lot of people use the past simple. Like these sentences, "I never did that" "I always do that"