# Has/ have verb third form today or did the second form today

Tags: grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

Learning grammar mistakes, today I found a sentence [I have visited Niagara falls last weekend](https://www.engvid.com/english-resource/50-common-grammar-mistakes-in-english/) incorrect. The correct form “I visited Niagara falls last weekend” so

**She has done it today.**
**She has done it yesterday**

Are these both sentences incorrect, or the first one is correct and the second is incorrect?

Comment: 1) Is the first sentence meant to contain "has" twice? That would certainly be a mistake. 2) If you delete one of the "has"s, then the only difference between the sentences is that one is "today" and one is "yesterday." Since there can be parts of today that are in the past, there's no problem with using past tenses with "today." Did you mean to ask about simple past tense, "She did it"? 3) Just because simple past is the best choice for the Niagara sentence doesn't mean that present perfect can't also be the right choice at other times.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I have never felt VS I never felt](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/62581/i-have-never-felt-vs-i-never-felt)

Comment: Two times has was a typo. I am asking which one is correct . She has done it yesterday or she has done it today

Comment: The first one (today) could be right, but not the second (yesterday). Your Niagara link should have prompted "She did it yesterday". You could also simply say "She has done it" without saying when. It's as much a matter of usage as grammar.

Answer (score 1):

She has done it today. **That is okay if the day is not finished.**

She did it yesterday. **That is correct. Yesterday is finished.**

We don't use present prefect with specific times likes yesterday, two hours ago, last night. Those trigger the simple past.

Answer (score 0):

Typically we use the past tense when we add the time or date that we did/heard/observed something.

**I visited the library yesterday.**
**I saw his plane depart last week.**

But we often make an exception to this rule when we are still in the period in which the events have occurred, preferring to use the present perfect.

**She has just finished / He has just left**.

**He has been busy this morning/today/this week/all month.**

If the time concerned has already passed, we would generally use the past tense.

**He was busy this morning/today etc but will be able to assist you tomorrow/at the weekend.**

There is a grey area between the two. You can often choose either tense.

So you might well hear: **She has done it today** as an alternative to **She did it today**, if it is still "today".

But you would never hear: **She has done it yesterday/last week.** That simply jars. Here the past tense is required.

Regarding you example. Somebody might well say: **I have visited Niagara Falls;** adding (I was there) **last weekend**, where **I was there** is omitted but understood. But here, **last weekend** is an afterthought rather than part of the sentence.